# Page not found after setting up SSL on Apache

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I'm having trouble with page not found after setting up a SSL on my CentOS 7 with Apache. After I went through the whole process, the website loaded correctly using HTTPS, but if I click any link to another page, I get a 404 page not found error.

For example, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (the IP address) works, but XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/products doesn't.

This is my .htaccess file:"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

My VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

ServerAdmin root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public

<Directory /var/www/html/project>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: are those links relative? do they display https ....?

Comment: Yes, they are relative links and yes, I attempt to load them using https. But all I get is a 404 error. Except for the index page.

Comment: why are you using IP not the domain name

Comment: I still didn't bind my domain to my VPS.